# Visual Studio 2022 - Modules (Intellisense errors)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20, c++-modules

I have 3 files, namely engineering.cpp, engineering.ixx and system.ixx. Contents briefly are:

*system.ixx:*

```
export module sys;
export import :engineering;
```

*engineering.ixx*

```
module;

#include <string>
#include <vector>

export module sys:engineering;

namespace sys::engineering
{

    export class Psychrometry
    {
       //more code here
    }
}
```

*engineering.cpp*

```
module;

#include <sstream>

module sys:engineering;

namespace sys::engineering
{
     //implementation of the class
}
```

In *another cpp* file I use it as:

```
import sys;
sys::engineering::Psychrometry psy;
```

The project compiles and works well but in *engineering.cpp* intellisense gives 99+ errors and code-completion and other basic facilities dont work.

However, if I make the following change to *engineering.cpp*:

```
//instead of module sys:engineering
module sys;
```

Now intellisense works well and the project still compiles and works. However, to my understanding the first approach (*module sys:engineering*) is correct rather than (*module sys*).

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

(Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.2.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two module units cannot use the same module partition name. As such, `sys:engineering` cannot be used in two module units. No diagnostic is required, which is why you don't get a compile error.

Also, if engineering.cpp is going to be a module implementation *partition*, then it must explicitly import the module if you want to use any of the declarations exported by the module interface. Non-partition implementation units automatically import the module interface.

The only reason to make a module implementation unit a partition is if you want to import that file elsewhere (perhaps to share declarations internal to the module). Otherwise, just make them non-partition implementation units.

Comment: In synch with the first paragraph of your answer, I guess I missed the part *"Unfortunately, there is a caveat when using implementation files in combination with partitions: there
can be only one file with a certain partition name"* from Professional C++ (Wrox).

Comment: @macroland: I don't now why that book sees this as "unfortunate". The whole point of using *any* partition name is to be able to import it elsewhere. If you are not writing something that needs to be imported, then there's no point in naming a partition. And if you do want to import it, then you *need* the name to uniquely identify a particular module unit.

Comment: Not sure but although initially it seems confusing to write `module sys` rather than `module sys:engineering`, the former is in line with the consumption of the module, `import sys`.